# Unable to import sqlite3 using Anaconda Python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, sqlite, anaconda, importerror

I am trying to do the following in Python 3.7.1 on Windows

```
import sqlite3
```

but I get the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have searched for a solution to the problem for quite a while now to no avail. I have also successfully run `pip install pysqlite3` on the Anaconda prompt, but the import still fails. What do?

Answer (score 181):

I got this working on windows by downloading: [the sqlite3 dll](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) **(find your system version)**

And placing it into the folder: `C:\Users\YOURUSER\Anaconda3\DLLs`

(Depending on how you installed **Anaconda**, this may have to be placed into
the following folder: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs`)

> According to @alireza-taghdisian, you can locate the exact path of
> your conda environments (where you need to copy the sqlite3 dll) by typing:
> `conda info --envs` on your **anaconda prompt**.

Comment: Also, you have to copy the file into the DLL folder that is inside of  your environment folder if you are using a conda virtual environment

Comment: Worked for me. But the path to my folder is: C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\DLLs

Comment: Worked for me.  Problem occured running Python 3.7.1 in VS Code.  I put the sqlite3.dll (site suggested by elgsantos) in the *anaconda/envs/* that I was running python.exe.

Comment: I'm using virtualenv created by anaoncda on Windows. Putting sqlite3.dll in the anaconda\DLLs folders doesn't work, however, when I put it into virtualenv's scripts folders, the problem is solved.

Comment: But I already have an `_sqlite.pyd` file in that folder.  That's good enough for command line python in the same virtual environment.  Why isn't it good enough for Anaconda when both share the same `~\Anaconda3\DLLs` folder in `sys.path`?

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks saved lot of time. It initially gave " from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'"
'sessionmanager.py' had problem could not import sqlite3 and was falling back on by this script
"try:
    import sqlite3
except ImportError:
    # fallback on pysqlite2 if Python was build without sqlite
        from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
"
Good Catch :)

Comment: Just in case if you have the problem with virtual env, download the file and put it in the `venv\Scripts\` directory and thanks

Comment: I had this problem with VS Code and Miniconda3. I had to copy `sqlite3.dll` _and_ `sqlite3.def` that came in the Windows sqlite download package to `~/.conda/envs/<env_name>/DLLs`. And then it worked. Yippee 

Answer (score 23):

Locate the **sqlite3.dll** file. In my case it was in following folder

```
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Library\bin
```

where `C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3` is the folder where Anaconda was installed

Add this to PATH in environment variables, and it should work then.

Comment: How do I add to the PATH variable? In VS code.

Comment: In Pycharm you can add a PATH environment variabele under Run->Edit Configurations->Environment Variables. The benefit of this is that you can specify different paths for different python versions

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. So probably a combination of elgsantos' answer if you don't already have the dll, and this one where you would add it to the PATH, is the complete answer.

Comment: For me, the folder was C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin

Answer (score 15):

Try copying the  sqlite3.dll from the

> C:\Users\YOURUSER\anaconda3\Library\bin

folder to

> C:\Users\YOURUSER\Anaconda3\DLLs

Comment: I just reinstalled anaconda (with python3.8, 64Bit, on Win10) but there is no bin folder under ...anaconda3\Library. The sqlite3.dll is in ...anaconda3\pkgs\sqlite-3.35.4-h2bbff1b_0\Library\bin instead. Is that to be considered strange? Of course, I could create the folder  ...anaconda3\Library\bin and copy the sqlite3.dll in there as a single .dll file. Would that be normal and OK?

Answer (score 11):

Please check https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4332
I added *anaconda root*/Library/bin to my PATH and now it works!

Comment: Did not help in my case or rather: that *is* already in my PATH and it still doesn't work. :-(

Answer (score 9):

Add CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1 to your environment variables.

Answer (score 5):

before executing the program, enter `conda activate` in your shell.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by putting **sqlite3.dll** file in the C:\Users<USERID>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs<ENV NAME>\DLLs.

Download sqlite3.dll file from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html
or copy it from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\

Comment: For me, the problem started after updating windows 11 after a spyder crash. This solution worked for  me

Answer (score 1):

I had tried all above solutions But for me and my system I got to know that
I downloaded Python in C:\Python27 hence there is dll folder in python C:\Python27\DLLs
I installed Sqlite3.dll in my above dll folder

May be this solution will help you because it completely depends on where do you install your python
Happy coding :)

Comment: When you'll get 50 reputation, remember to use comments for such tips.

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems. Try to improve that. Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments. To highlight apps' names or interface, use a **bold** (`**` brackets) or *italic* (`*` brackets) font. To start from a new line use *double space* at the end of the line - the question'll be way more clear than using *Enter* everywhere. Adding some `:` would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

I put the sqlite3.dll in the path folder of my Python venv and still wont work. I suspected it is a path problem.

*(In my case: E:\Virtual_Env\mini_zinc\env\Scripts)*

I found in my case I messed up installation in a virtual evn, somehow using an anaconda python kernel within a Python venv.

I reinstall the Python Venv and check the python version after installed Env is correct (not the Anaconda python),  then proceed with Jupyter Notebook (or Juyterlab) and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the @elgsantos useful. But for those who are new to Python and Conda like me, I would like to add a little bit of details.

1- I use miniconda3 for creating new environment.

2- interestingly, I got two installation path on my computer for conda: the first one (the obvious) is located on "C:\Users\taghdisian\miniconda3". The second one is on "C:\Users\taghdisian\AppData\Local\r-miniconda". The latter is the primary path that you need to copy your sqlite3 files into the envs folder. I copy them in the "C:\Users\taghdisian\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\sdr3.9\DLLs" in which the sdr3.9 is one of my virtual Condo environment.

you can locate the exact path of your conda environments (where you need to copy sqlite3) by typing the `conda info --envs` on your anaconda prompt.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

got the same error while loading the jupyter notebook from other conda prompt than "base" environment.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DW7E.png
*Resolved by installing sqlite package
(nlpenv) C:\Users\arunk>conda install sqlite*

launching
*

> (nlpenv) C:\Users\arunk>jupyter notebook

- 