# Django DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, django, anaconda

Hello i m new at django.  I installed all moduoles from anaconda. Then created a web application with

```
django-admin startproject
```

My project crated successfully. No problem

Then i tried to run that project at localhost to see is everything okay or not. And i run that code in command line

```
python manage.py runserver
```

And i get that error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors. 
<locals>.wrapper at 0x00000221B6D45A60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in 
inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
raise _exception[1]
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", 
line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
app_config.import_models()
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", 
line 198, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in 
import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _ 
find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in 
_call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, 
BaseUserManager
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 101, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 305, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, 
connection.ops.max_name_length())
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", 
line 33, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", 
line 202, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", 
line 110, in load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in    
import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 10, in <module>
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in 
<module>
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
File "C:\Users\Sercan\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
<module>
from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Can someone tell me where do i make mistake and how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: how did you solve the error?

Comment: This answer should be able to solve it; https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642416/10031694

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem. I solved it by running it in the Anaconda shell.

1. Open **Anaconda Shell/terminal** by pressing your Windows key and searching Anaconda
2. Go to the directory you have your django project in
3. `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Just had the same problem. Thank you so much theEconCsEngineer. You saved hours of searching for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to install SQLite:

https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Or you could change the database settings in your settings file to use some other database.

Answer (score 0):

Remove anaconda

Download and install from python.org in c:\python37. Here it will be easy to set variables

Setup python variables

Don't forget to select pip while installing python.

Path:c:\python37,c:\python32\Scripts

If you want to install django on a virtual environment install virtualevmwrapper-win

Voila! It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use anaconda then follow below steps

> conda create --name MyDjangoEnv(virtual environment) Django
>
> press y to install. before press y please make sure correct version of software are selected
>
> activate myDjangoEnv
>
> conda info --envs
>
> conda install django
>
> conda install sqlparse
>
> django-admin startproject first_project

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in this site: http://felipegalvao.com.br/blog/2017/01/03/como-criar-ambientes-e-instalar-o-django-com-distribuicao-anaconda/

Basically, you need to activate an environment in your anaconda prompt.

Step 1: `conda info --envs`

Step 2 : `conda create --name env_name python=3`

Step 3: `pip install django`

Step 4: Assuming that you already created a startproject, run the manage.py runserver

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, it simply means that dll module is not installed in that path while creating a project don't go with first option i.e venv(virtual environment) this will not let modules to import in your project.., go with the second option for interpreter and select your respective python.exe.

> > run the below commands in terminal
> >     django-admin
> >     if it shows error then

```
pip install django
```

thanks.