# Create django project with PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am trying to create the Django project but it poped up a dialog with these messages. Can anyone help me why it happened?
[image]

Comment: this is an issue with anaconda, you should try `python manage.py runserver` through the anaconda shell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655666/django-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)