# Not Able to Launch jupyter from Anaconda 2019.03

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, sublime-anaconda

I am working on Win10, 64bit. I have installed "Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64". When I am going to launch Jupyter from Anaconda,the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\usatapat\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 10, in 
import sqlite3
File "C:\Users\usatapat\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in 
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
File "C:\Users\usatapat\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\usatapat\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\usatapat\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 86, in 
from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
File "C:\Users\usatapat\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 13, in 
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2' "
```

I have uninstalled and installed anaconda. But still this issue not resolved.

Comment: You don't have pysqlite2 installed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346965/running-jupyter-notebook-from-cmd-raises-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-py

Comment: I solved the same error with the response:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642416/5321903](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642416/5321903)