# Python Azure Function in Visual Studio Code - DLL Error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am trying to run a script which imports all the packages required for a code in visual studio code (there is nothing else in their at the moment apart from the import statements) all packages are installed on the environment being used.
However running just the statement

[image: entered code]

It returns the error message 
[image: visual studio output]

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling all packages, changing to a different environment and creating a whole new azure function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use conda?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is missing a sqlite3 DLL file in your anaconda path `C:\Users\954198\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\DLLs`.

Meanwhile, there is an existing SO thread [Unable to import sqlite3 using Anaconda Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876404/unable-to-import-sqlite3-using-anaconda-python) which got the same issue with yours, please follow the answer of most voted up to add the lack sqlite dll file to fix it.

I'm afraid that your conda environment or your python environment may be broken, `sqlite3` is a default package pre-installed in Python.