# Error when running sqlite3 on Pycharm (Windows 10)

Tags: python, sqlite, anaconda

I am trying to do the following in Python 3.7.6 on Windows on Pycharm:

```
import sqlite3
```

However, this error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gusta/PycharmProjects/SiteCompilado/Compilador.py", line 8, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "C:\Users\gusta\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\gusta\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
```

I've tried to `pip install sqlite3` but I get the following message on the terminal:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sqlite3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sqlite3
```

And when I go to *File > Settings > Add (Available Packages)* it can't seem to find sqlite3 library.

Comment: I've already tried adding the sqlite3.dll to the Anaconda3/DLLs folder but it was already there. What to do?

Comment: You’re using Conda? If so, please provide the contents of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to this question here,

[Unable to import sqlite3 using Anaconda Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876404/unable-to-import-sqlite3-using-anaconda-python)

Tried it once but it didn't seem to work, then I restarted the computer, tried again and now it's working.