# Mobile Security Framework (MobSF) Installation issue

Tags: python-3.x, testing, owasp, android-security, security-framework

**=======================MobSF Clean Script for Windows=======================**
Running this script will delete the Scan database, all files uploaded and generated.
C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\scripts
Deleting all Uploads
Deleting all Downloads
Deleting Static Analyzer Migrations
Deleting Dynamic Analyzer Migrations
Deleting MobSF Migrations
Deleting temp and log files
Deleting DB
Deleting Secret File
Deleting Previous Setup files
Done
**[INSTALL] Migrating Database**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\manage.py", line 14, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in 
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in 
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in **new**
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py", line 28, in **getattr**
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in **getitem**
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 14, in 
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3__init__.py", line 23, in 
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
    from _sqlite3 import *
**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Traceback (most recent call last):**

  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\manage.py", line 14, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in 
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in 
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in **new**
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py", line 28, in **getattr**
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in **getitem**
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 14, in 
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3__init__.py", line 23, in 
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
    from _sqlite3 import *
**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Traceback (most recent call last):**

  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\manage.py", line 14, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in 
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in 
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in **new**
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py", line 28, in **getattr**
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in **getitem**
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 14, in 
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3__init__.py", line 23, in 
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
    from _sqlite3 import *
**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Traceback (most recent call last):**

  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\manage.py", line 14, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in 
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in 
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in **new**
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py", line 28, in **getattr**
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in **getitem**
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 14, in 
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3__init__.py", line 23, in 
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
    from _sqlite3 import 

***ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

[***] Reading config file..
[*] Creating other folders...

[*] Downloading nuget..
[*] Saving to File nuget.exe

[*] Downloading and installing Binskim...
[*] Downloading BinScope..

[*] Saving to File C:\Users\DELL\MobSF\Tools\BinScope\BinScope_x64.msi
[*] Installing BinScope to C:\Users\DELL\MobSF\Tools\BinScope
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in 
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in 
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in **new**
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py", line 28, in **getattr**
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in **getitem**
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 14, in 
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3__init__.py", line 23, in 
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
    from _sqlite3 import *
**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Traceback (most recent call last):**

  File "manage.py", line 14, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in 
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in 
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in **new**
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py", line 28, in **getattr**
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in **getitem**
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 14, in 
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3__init__.py", line 23, in 
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
    from _sqlite3 import *
**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Traceback (most recent call last):**

  File "manage.py", line 14, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in 
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in 
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in **new**
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py", line 28, in **getattr**
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in **getitem**
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 14, in 
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3__init__.py", line 23, in 
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
    from _sqlite3 import *
**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Download and Install wkhtmltopdf for PDF Report Generation - https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

[INSTALL] Installation Complete**

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved...
There is missing sqlite3.dll file in C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\DLLs. 
Check following Answer help me.
[Answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642416/5989569)