# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.8

I'm trying to run a `.py` program on a CMD terminal
but I get the following error :

```
from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: The specified module could not be found.
```

PS : I am using python 3.8 and I had created a virtual enlivenment for my application

Comment: If you created a virtual environment using `virtualenv`, try to create one with `conda`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642416/13697228